# HTML5 Progress Bar Pause when in another tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My progress bar loader which i'm using to display a sorten amount of seconds while my page is loading in Javascript is having some trouble.

If i click another tab while its counting it will pause, and will only resume when you go back.
How would i go by allowing it to count even though you're in another tab

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        if(!Modernizr.meter){
            alert('Sorry your brower does not support HTML5 progress bar');
        } else {
            var progressbar = $('#progressbar'),
                max = progressbar.attr('max'),
                time = (800/max)*10,    
                value = progressbar.val();

            var loading = function() {
                value += 1;
                addValue = progressbar.val(value);

                $('.progress-value').html(value + '%');

                if (value == max) {
                    clearInterval(animate);     $(".demo-wrapper").remove();   $("#details").fadeIn("slow");     $("#motion1").html("Report for Registration.");        $("#motion").remove();   
                }
                    if (value == 1) {
                        $("#motion").html("Loading Page..");   
                }
                      if (value == 86) {
                        $("#motion").html("Connecting..");   
                }
            };

            var animate = setInterval(function() {
                loading();
            }, time);
        };


    });
```

Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/w977Q/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at the accepted answer here: [How can I make setInterval also work when a tab is inactive in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome)

It appears this is basically a function of the browser not wanting to use processing power on tabs that aren't in focus.

Answer (score -1):

## Hope this helps you

```
setInterval('yourFunction();', 1000); // this will work even on other tab
```

and

```
setInterval(yourFunction, 1000);      // this will run only if on current tab
```

Comment: Comment if there is any prob

Comment: just tested it on chrome 60.0.3112.101 and my function is not longer called if I change tab... also can you explain why it is supposed to work?

Comment: Down vote because both functions get executed when you close the tabs. At least when you keep the Chrome Dev Tools open. I was surprised that `setInterval('yourFunction();', 1000);` even works, but it does.